# HTML5 Database to verify exist table?

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

Is there a way to verify whether the table is exist inside the database in HTML5 local database?

I need to create 9 tables, and this method will run when the document ready. If each time the page start, it also calling the same method, will it not be waste of memory? I using it for the mobile device (iPhone).

This is the code:

```
try{
                if(!window.openDatabase){
                    alert('DB not supported.');
                }else{
                    var shortName = 'abc';
                    var version = '1.0';
                    var displayName = 'ABC';
                    var maxSize = 3145728;
                    var tableName = ['business', 'politic', 'firstread', 'commentary','features', 'insiderasia', 'management', 'media'];
                    db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);

                    $.each(tableName, function(theCount, value){
                        db.transaction(
                            function(transaction){
                                transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '+  value +' (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, link TEXT NOT NULL, title TEXT NOT NULL, author TEXT NOT NULL, pubdate TEXT NOT NULL, imgLink TEXT NULL, desc TEXT NOT NULL, day TEXT NOT NULL);');
                        });
                    });
                }
            }catch(e){
                if(e == INVALID_STATE_ERR){
                    console.log('invalid database version.');
                }else{
                    console.log('unknown error ' + e + '.');
                }
                return;
            }
```

Comment: you mean you have markup inside a field on the database wich you want to check wether it contains a table or not?

Comment: what mean markup inside a field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you need this? If you worry about that you can recreate table that already exist in your database, you need creating your table with this SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name
```

Comment: I have use this 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', but I need to create 9 tables, and this method will run when the document ready. If each time the page start, it also calling the same method, will it not be waste of memory? I using it for the mobile device (iPhone).

Comment: That's good article can help you — http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/03/html5-web-sql-database-intro-to-versioning-and-migrations/

or you can store flag in localStorage after you create all your tables and on document ready before doing anything at first check this flag but it's not recommend because user can clear localStorage but save databases.

Comment: I thought using localStorage is a good idea, but as to you said, user might clear the localStorage.

What if I only create a single tables on the document ready? other table will only create when user go to other 'page'? will it be better if create 9 tables?

Comment: I don't think that it would be better. Try to use migration schema that was presented at article that I wrote above. The source code of migrator you can find at github — https://github.com/nanodeath/JS-Migrator it's simple and straightforward approach for your case